# How can I set Content-Type automatically when using express.static()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was building a server with express that uses

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

to serve any static file requests that come by. The problem is that the code doesn't automatically set the Content-Type header (or any header it seems, correct me if I'm wrong). In the documentation for `express.static()`, they say you could send in an `options` object as a second parameter to `express.static()` and specify a function that would set any headers, like

```
app.use(express.static("public", {
  setHeader : function (res, path, stat) {
    //some code to set headers
  }
}));
```

The documentation I read is [here](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#express.static).

The problem with this that I found is that you'd have to write code to set the header individually for each file type. And even if I decided to do that, I found no way to access the filename of the file that is being served. Is there a standard way of doing this?